# How do I declare a dependency on an ng-metadata module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-decorator

I have a project that is using `ng-metadata` (https://github.com/ngParty/ng-metadata) to build a handful of Angular 1.5 modules. I have a test module/component that looks like this:

```
import { NgModule, Component, Inject, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from 'ng-metadata/core'
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from 'ng-metadata/platform-browser-dynamic'

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    template: require('./test.template.html')
})
class TestComponent {

    @Input() type: string;

    constructor() {
        console.log(`test: ${this.type}`)
    }

}

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent]
})
class HeroModule {}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(HeroModule)
```

Everything seems happy when compiled and I'm now attempting to use the module in another project (that is *not* using `ng-metadata` but has a compatible version of Angular).

I'm simply including the shims as directed by the `ng-metadata` docs and the JavaScript file that contains the module described above (built by webpack). I have a new module in this project that wants to list the `HeroModule` as a dependency. I've tried a few things:

```
// attempt 1:
angular.module('my-consuming-module', ['ui.router', 'hero'])

// attempt 2:
angular.module('my-consuming-module', ['ui.router', 'heroModule'])

// attempt 3:
angular.module('my-consuming-module', ['ui.router', 'hero-module'])
```

All always end up with the same `Error: $injector:nomod Module Unavailable` error from Angular.

If I'm using `ng-metadata` to build my modules, what are the names I use to list them as dependencies in another project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured this out! It's amazing what happens when you carefully read documentation...

Found in the [Manual Angular 1 Bootstrap](https://github.com/ngParty/ng-metadata/blob/master/docs/recipes/bootstrap.md#manual-angular-1-angularbootstrap) section of ng-metadata's docs:

> You can still leverage ng2 way of components registration without ng-metadata bootstrap, but you have to manually create your Angular 1 module from an ng-metadata @NgModule using the bundle helper function.

I ended up being able to do the following:

```
// REMOVED platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(HeroModule)  
const Ng1AdminModule = bundle(HeroModule).name;
export const AppModule = angular.module('hero', [Ng1AdminModule]);
```

And then my `hero` module becomes accessible to the `my-consuming-module` just as I expected. The **bundle helper function** was the key to figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import those module from their respective locations and inject it inside your angular module

```
//ensure `angular`, `angular-ui-router` should be there in `map` of systemjs.config.js
import * as angular from 'angular';
import * as uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import { heroModule} from './hero.module';

angular.module('app',[ uiRouter, heroModule]);
```

Check references [here](https://hotell.gitbooks.io/ng-metadata/content/docs/recipes/startup-logic.html#configurationrouting)

Comment: The project using `ng-metadata` is intended to be a library. The other projects aren't necessarily using TypeScript and the intent is that they would just be able to include the JavaScript and an Angular module. Is this not possible with `ng-metadata` ?

Comment: @amlyhamm not sure, I just read documentation and answered here :(